# Show that $AD=2AP$ if and only if $BP \perp CP$.

Tags: geometry

Let the incircle of $\triangle ABC$ contact $AB,AC,BC$ at $D,E,F$ respectively, and intersect $AF$ at a second point $P$. Show that $AD=2AP$ if and only if $BP \perp CP$.

Comment: What is your trying?

Answer (score 1):

## Proof

Denote the intersection point of $DE$ and $BC$ as $G$. Then $$(AB,AC|AF,AG)=(BC|FG)=-1,\tag1$$which shows that $AF$ is the polar line of $G$ with respect to the incircle. Hence $GP$ is another tangent to the incircle, and $GP=GF.$ Moreover, notice that $DE$ is also the the polar line of $A$ with respect to the incircle. Hence $$(PF|KA)=-1.\tag2$$

Assume that $AD=2AP$. Notice that $AD^2=AP\cdot AF.$ Thus, by $(1)$ and $(2)$, we may readily obtain that $$AD:AP:PK:KF=10:5:3:12.\tag 3$$

By Menelaus theorem, we obtain $$\frac{AK}{KF}\cdot\frac{FG}{GB}\cdot\frac{BD}{DA}=1.$$
Thus $$\frac{PG}{GB}=\frac{FG}{GB}=\frac{DA}{BD}\cdot\frac{KF}{AK}=\frac{PF}{BF}\cdot\frac{DA}{AK} \cdot \frac{KF}{PF}=\frac{PF}{BF}\cdot\frac{10}{8} \cdot \frac{12}{15}=\frac{PF}{BF}.\tag 4$$

This implies that $PB$ bisects $\angle GPF$. By the properties of the harmonic point series, we may claim that $\angle BPC=90^o.$ (In fact, we may also prove that $PC$ bisects the exterior angle of $\angle GPF$, since $PG:PF=BG:BF=CG:CF$)

Till now, we have already proved that if $AD=2AP$ then $BP \perp CP.$ But obviously, by the almost perfectly similar reasoning process, we may also prove that if $BP \perp CP$ then $AD=2AP$. We are done!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In what follows we prove that if $AD=2AP$ then $BP \perp CP$. This proof can be rewritten so that it actually shows the equivalence of these conditions, but I'm too lazy to do it.

---

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $DF$ and let $PB$ intersect the incircle at $X$. Clearly $\triangle APD \sim \triangle ADF$, and therefore $\dfrac{PD}{DF} = \dfrac{AP}{AD} = \dfrac 12$. It follows that $PD = \dfrac 12 DF = DM$.

Observe that $PB$ is the $P$-symmedian of triangle $PDF$. Angle chasing yields $\triangle PDM \sim \triangle PXF$ and since $PD=DM$, we have $PX=XF$.

We prove analogously that $PY=YF$, where we let $PC$ intersect the incircle of $ABC$ at $Y$.

Therefore $XY$ is the perpendicular bisector of $PF$, therefore $XY$ is a diameter of the incircle of $ABC$. Thus $\angle BPC = \angle XPY = 90^\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a not-so-pretty partial solution.  I shall prove that, if $AD=2\cdot AP$, then $BP\perp CP$.  This is a trigonometric solution, so it is quite boring.

[image]

Without loss of generality, suppose that $\angle B\geq \angle C$.  Write $a:=BC$, $b:=CA$, $c:=AB$, and $s:=\dfrac{a+b+c}{2}$.  Note that $$AP\cdot AF=AD^2\,.$$
Thus,
$$PF=AF-AP=\frac{AF^2-AD^2}{AF}\,.$$
Let $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$.  Then,
$$PM^2=PF^2+FM^2+2\cdot PF\cdot FM\cdot\cos(\phi)\,,\tag{*}$$
where $\phi:=\angle AFB$.

We now find 
$$AF^2=AB^2+BF^2-2\cdot AB\cdot BF\cdot\cos(\angle ABC)=c^2+(s-b)^2-2c(s-b)\left(\frac{c^2+a^2-b^2}{2ca}\right)\,.$$
Thus,
$$AF^2=\frac{(s-a)}{2a}\left(a^2+(b+c)a-(b-c)^2\right)\,.\tag{#}$$
Therefore,
$$\cos(\phi)=\frac{AF^2+BF^2-AB^2}{2\cdot AF\cdot BF}=\frac{(b-c)(s-a)}{a\cdot AF}\,.$$
Note that $FM=\dfrac{b-c}{2}$.

From (*), we get
$$PM^2=\left(\frac{AF^2-AD^2}{AF}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b-c}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{AF^2-AD^2}{AF}\right)(b-c)\left(\frac{(b-c)(s-a)}{a\cdot AF}\right)\,.$$
Due to (#), we get 
$$AF^2-AD^2=\frac{s-a}{2a}\left(2a^2-(b-c)^2\right)\,.$$

If $AD=2\cdot AP$, then $AF=2\cdot AD=2(s-a)=b+c-a$, since $AD=s-a$.
Using (#), we see that
$$(b+c-a)^2=AF^2=\frac{(b+c-a)}{4a}\left(a^2+(b+c)a-2(b-c)^2\right)\,,$$
so
$$0=a^2+(b+c)a-2(b-c)^2-4a(b+c-a)=5a^2-3(b+c)a-2(b-c)^2\,.$$  From (*), we have
$$PM^2=\left(\frac{3}{2}AD\right)^2+\left(\frac{b-c}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}(b-c)^2\frac{(s-a)}{a}\,.$$
Using $AD=s-a$, we conclude that
$$PM^2-\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2=\frac{\big(a-3(b+c)\big)\left(5a^2-3a(b+c)-2(b-c)^2\right)}{16a}=0\,.$$
Consequently, $PM=\dfrac{a}{2}=BM=CM$.  That is, the circle with diameter $M$ passes through $P$, whence $\angle BPC=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: too complicated. See mine plz.

Comment: Where is yours then?  And I don't deny that this is an ugly solution.

Comment: you can see, now. I just posted.

Comment: No time to read it now, but it looks pretty, if it correct.  Will come back to read your solution later.  And don't be discouraged by close votes.  Your problems are interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Using classical geometry, the following demonstrates a sufficient condition for $AD=2AP$, and shows that $AD=2AP$ in turn implies $BP\perp CP$.

Let $DEF$ be the incircle of triangle $ABC$, and suppose $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles, with $AC=BC$, and$$\frac{AC}{AB}=\frac{2}{1}$$Join $AF$ crossing the circle at $P$, and join $PB$, $PC$, $CD$, $EF$, and $EP$ extended to $G$.

Since $\angle BDC$ is right, then $D$ bisects $AB$, making $AE=BF$, and $ABFE$ an isosceles trapezoid with$$EF\parallel AB$$Moreover, since $\triangle ABF$ shares the angle at $B$ with $\triangle ABC$, and $$\frac{AB}{BF}=\frac{2}{1}$$then$$\triangle ABF\sim \triangle ABC$$ [Euclid, *Elements VI, 6*], and $\triangle ABF$ is isosceles.
[image: AD=2AP]

Next, since $\angle AEG=\angle EFP$ [*Elements III, 32*], and alternate interior $\angle AGE=\angle FEP$, then$$\triangle AGE\sim \triangle EPF$$And it is evident that$$\triangle EPF\sim \triangle GPA$$Therefore$$\triangle AGE\sim\triangle GPA$$so that$$\angle AEG=\angle GAP=\angle ACB$$

and$$GE\parallel BC$$and hence$$\frac{AE}{AG}=\frac{2}{1}$$But $AE=AD$, and $AG=AP$. Therefore$$\frac{AD}{AP}=\frac{2}{1}$$.

**It remains to show that $\angle BPC$ is right**

In the figure below, with the same triangle $ABC$ and incircle $DEF$, draw $DJ$ parallel to $BC$ and join $PD$, $DF$, $FJ$, and $PB$. We do not know yet if $J$ lies on $PC$, and instead of drawing $PC$, join $PJ$, $JC$, and draw $JH$ tangent at $J$.

Since it is easily shown that $DBHJ$ is an isosceles trapezoid, and that $\angle JHB=\angle DBH=\angle KFB$, therefore $KF$ is equal and parallel to $JH$, so that$$\angle PFC=\angle JHC$$And since $AK$=$KF$, and $AP$ was shown to be half of $AD=AK$, making $AP=PK$, then with $AP=1$ we have $PF=3$ and $FC=6$, so that$$\frac{PF}{FC}=\frac{1}{2}$$[image: right angle at P]And since $JH=DB=2$ and $HC=4$, then$$\frac{JH}{HC}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Therefore, $\triangle PFC\sim\triangle JHC$ [*Elements VI, 6*], and $PJ$, $JC$ lie in one straight line.

Now since by parallels$$\angle PCB=\angle PJD$$and by *Elements III, 32*$$ \angle PJD=\angle ADP$$then $\angle PCB$ and $\angle PDB$ are supplementary, and $PDBC$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. And since $\angle BDC$ is right, then $BC$ is the diameter of the circle through $P$, $D$, $B$, $C$, and therefore $\angle BPC$ is right.